# QueryDSL JPAAnnotation Processor generate QModel for a single class

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, querydsl, jpa-annotations

I have a class that's located in a package. In that package I have several JPAEntities. However all I want for the JPAAnnotationProcessor to do is to generate QModel for a single class. Not for all classes inside that package. Is that possible without moving the class to another package?

Comment: Are you using hibernate? Are you using annotations or XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@QueryExclude` annotation on top of the classes for which you don't want `QClass` to be generated.

```
import com.mysema.query.annotations.QueryExclude

@Entity
@QueryExclude
public class MyEntity {}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to solve the problem in package level atm. If you mark all package with `@QueryExclude` and single class with `@QueryEntity`, still the whole package will be excluded. Therefore you have to mark each class separately.